# Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook 2013

Tags: gmail, synchronization, directory, office-2013

I am using business google accounts  and I would use them with Microsoft Office 2013, for this purpose I have downloaded the "Google Apps sync for Microsoft Outlook" 2013 I am using my accounts on different computers with different office's versions and actually is working fine with outlook 2010 but with M.O. 2013 I can see the folders'tree but not their contents.
I tried already to remake everything from the cratch, I've tried with a new profile too but nothing the result doesn't change I can see the tree and I can even see the number in the brackets in bold that tells me the number of the email should contain the folder but when I click on it I cannot see anything inside, do you have any idea on that?

Sorry for my English,

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this was, uninstalled office 2013 e installed office 2010.
Google App Sync for Microsoft Outlook doesn't work with the 2013 version.
Thank you all